Spontaneous symmetry-breaking for flat worlds
As far as the inhabitants of the universe are concerned, their world is an infinite plane dividing the empty half of the universe from the rock-filled half of the universe, and "down" is an objective universal direction.
Turns out, they just haven't done enough Science yet.
The world may or may not be spatially infinite, but the depth of rock below is definitely finite, and if you get far enough above the surface, "down" stops meaning much. In fact, space is totally isotropic, just as in our universe, but for some reasons, large accumulations of matter undergo spontaneous symmetry breaking and arrange themselves into roughly-circular planes instead of spheres. Far, far away there may even be "domain wall" defects where one world-plane intersects another that started accreting somewhere else in the universe and broke spatial symmetry in a different direction.
Clearly, this universe doesn't have gravity as we know it. But what sort of alternative force, or forces, could it have that would cause matter to behave this way?

I'm curious if this even has an answer, but keep in mind we also have asymmetric mysteries in our universe such as the baryonic asymmetry

@JustAnotherUser I am hopeful about the existence of an answer due to the existence of ferromagnetism, a case of spontaneous matter-associated symmetry breaking in our own universe.

To clarify: you're asking what symmetry/alternative force could be broken to cause matter to collect into cylindrical disk-shaped objects instead of spheres?

@controlgroup Specifically discs--squished in the linear axis, spread out in the radial axis. Radial symmetry is not actually important, it's just the default if the plane remain isotropic. But yeah, what alternative force laws associated with matter could cause it to spontaneously break spatial symmetry and organized into discs instead of spheres.

Out of curiosity, why would you explain gravity via 'our' science at all? If you state that gravity is an equal force pulling down across the plane, it will be so. If you go with 'our' science, you'll also run into problems with black holes, as you have infinite rock below. You already have different science from the start, what is a little 'gravity feels like a flat Eather thinks it works' added?

@Trioxidane I don't want to explain it with our science. I want to figure out what scientists in this universe might conclude about it, given the observation that gravity works that way.

Voronoi Diagrams
In 3D, boundaries between Voronoi cells are flat planes. Make your matter accumulate along them, and you will have flat planets.

One way to do this could be "white holes". Have one type of matter which tends to clump into compact objects and another type which tends to get as far as possible from matter I. Let this be the source of "gravity" instead of matter II attracting itself.
The bubbles between your flat worlds are not exactly "totally isotropic" in this case since you have the white holes in them, but maybe you are happy with this because you may not notice the white holes at all as long as you are in free fall away from them.
If you don't want white holes, there are other ways to get something like Voronoi diagrams. Soap bubbles do it without having a white hole in their center. So, maybe empty space itself repels matter, like the air in a bubble, and you don't feel anything when you are mid-air because the repulsive forces from every direction cancel out. Combine this with more complex interactions between matter -- cohesion on some distances, repulsion on others, like you have in real bubble liquid.
You may need interactions between "matter II" anyway, to make sure it clumps along the Voronoi faces rather than edges or corners... but hey, you didn't say "hard science".

The problem with this - unless visibility is limited somehow - is that you'll see the other faces of the voronoi cells.  The world won't look like a limitless plane.

@MontyWild Does that matter? The question specifies there may be other planes in the universe. Also, people who see the other planes don't need to know what they are seeing.

If the bubbles are big enough, each face would seem effectively infinite.

The fundamental workings of this universe would have to be quite different to that of our own.  In our own universe, gravity attracts all objects equally in all directions, but in the OP's universe gravity would have to work differently (as would many other things).
So, I propose that in the OP's universe, gravity is necessarily biased toward being directional, orthogonal to the plane of a mass' spin or parallel (and antiparallel) to the axis of spin.
In this universe, an accumulation of matter would probably still spin as in our own universe, but its gravity would be very much stronger orthogonal to the plane of that rotation than in the plane of rotation, though it would still be necessary to have some lateral gravity.  This would lead to matter accumulating into disks, not spheres.  The disks may be somewhat thicker at their centres than their edges.
The universe could still be isotropic, since the axis of rotation of a world disc could be oriented in any direction.  It would be only the fact that the world is rotating that causes gravity to be biased.
This would also have the effect that spheres of mass could form, but only if they are not rotating at all, or at least not rotating to any significant degree.
Of course, this doesn't explain how an object such as a star might form, unless it is assumed that stars have no significant spin.
The OP would have to decide how much spin is 'significant'.
There could concievably be a case in which two world disks could approach one-another.  Because the universe is still isotropic, there is nothing that constrains the two disks to have the same axis of spin, and they could easily be aligned quite differently.  If they collided, that would necessarily lead to an averaging of their angular and overall momentum, in a disaster similar to the collision of two astronomical bodies in our own universe.  This would most likely result in one or more new disk bodies with different axes of spin.

Leave the laws of physics as we know them unchanged but introduce a new fundamental particle. Let this particle be similar to a water molecule, and let it be the most abundant particle in the universe. The particle interacts with gravity and light like most normal matter.
The H-O-H structure of water means that when it crystalizes, it often forms flat crystals (aka snowflakes). This only happens at a specific temperature for reasons that -- as far as I know -- have not yet been explained. But we know that when the crystal is seeded with flat structure, then it continues to expand as a flat structure.
Similarly, the new particle will prefer to form flat crystals because of its electrical properties. It bonds really well with itself, and so forms very large plates. Normal matter is attracted to the gravity of these plates and mounds up on them. There will be some bulge in the center of the plates compared to the edges, but overall, the worlds would be flat.

I know there are various challenges to this approach, but I think they’re more easily resolved than a new force affecting every physical process. Help to improve this answer is welcome.

The atoms in this universe have an "ecliptic", thus atomic bonding tends towards flat arrangements. Not all bonds will be "horizontally" arranged electrons do still orbit on other paths but instead of the electron cloud of an atom being basically spherical they are now extremely oblate so flat structures are massively more stable than other forms. The interaction between this oblate bonding and the underlying quantum structure of the local hubble bubble leads to all objects in the local group sitting along a single plane. Given that our current understanding of gravity is limited to "sufficiently dense energy concentrations (known as matter) exert it" any note on this would be premature and highly speculative.

That doesn't explain apparent gravity.

@MontyWild I knew someone would say that, given that we can't explain apparent gravity in our existing universe anything in that department would be purely speculative.

Planets are not held together by inter-atomic bonds.

@AlexP And this universe is not forming planets.

OK, not planets, but "large structures". Large structures are not held together by inter-atomic bonds.

@AlexP Ours aren't because we have a gravitational force acting to pull things into spheres, this universe clearly doesn't, something has to drive structural development in the place of spherical gravity the only other force we know of that can drive the formation of structure (in our universe crystallisation) is interatomic interaction.
